# Infinity vs. mantl

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing, mesosphere

I recently stumbled upon http://mantl.io/ and https://mesosphere.com/infinity/. However, I am unsure about the advantages of each approach.

So far I know **mantl** integrates some components like ELK, calico, vault, traefik which are nice to have out of the box for a common application. Whereas **infinity** seems to be well suited for IOT /big-data analytics applications.

Can you help me to explain the difference / advantages of each approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit comparing apples and oranges. Infinity is what we call a DCOS stack, it's a combo of different services (in this case Kafka, Spark, C*, and Akka) for a specific domain, in this case IoT apps.

I wouldn't say that ELK is a unique thing to mantl, since it's also [available on the DCOS](https://github.com/mesosphere/multiverse/tree/version-1.x/repo/packages/E/elasticsearch/1) and in fact I did [install ES](https://twitter.com/mhausenblas/status/651417553269575680) on DCOS myself a while ago, with little effort. The same is true for [Vault](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/vault-dcos), etc.

DCOS comes with a [number of services](https://docs.mesosphere.com/services/overview/), growing every week, ready to be used in different application areas: from pure stateless deployments (for example a Web server farm) to CI/CD envs to analytics (and IoT).